# Can a dual US-Bulgarian citizen travel to the Schengen area with a passport that expires in 3 months?

Tags: schengen, passports

I have the following situation: I'm travelling next week with my children from Chicago-via Berlin- to Sofia (Bulgaria). We all have dual citizenship and both passports- US and Bulgarian. My US passport and my son's too expire Sept 18, 2015. Our Bulgarian passports are ok. We are planning a return from Sofia-via Berlin- to Chicago on Aug 12. I was told by my agent to check about the NEW VALIDITY rule of Germany. Can someone help? My logic tells me that we will make it to Bulgaria, but on the way back will the German authorities let us come back to the US?

Answer (score 7):

As a Bulgarian passport holder, you are an EU citizen. Germany cannot prevent you from entering Germany on the basis of your citizenship. You should have no problem returning to the US through Berlin.

At check-in on your return trip, the airline will check your US passport to ensure that you have the right to enter the US in Chicago.

When passing through exit passport control in Berlin, be sure to use the same passport that you used to enter Berlin. This will probably be your Bulgarian passport, as the Schengen visa rules require that visitors have a passport valid for 3 months after the planned date of departure, and your US passports do not meet that requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, my logic tells me the same, but they have advise me otherwise.

Comment: Does your agent know you hold valid Bulgarian passports? It would be an issue with only your US passports, but you have a better alternative.

Comment: @iva I am also a dual US/EU citizen. I always identify myself to EU authorities using my EU passport. Doing this will make your life rather simpler. If anyone says that your US passports are not eligible for entry to Germany, you should explain to them that you will not be using your US passport to enter Germany, but your Bulgarian one. As an EU national, you have a right to enter Germany, and your Bulgarian passport is documentary evidence of that right. (Furthermore, since Bulgaria and US are both outside Schengen, you don't actually need to pass immigration control in Berlin.)

Comment: In fact, I talked to US national passport center - they are telling me that Bulgarian authorities would not let me fly back to the US since my passport will not be valid for over 3 months.

Comment: @iva As a US citizen, there is no requirement on passport validity to enter the US. It might be harder if your passport has actually expired, but there is certainly no 3 month requirement. I would suggest getting a second opinion on that.

Comment: Who requires it - is Bulgaria, they told me, when leaving the country to go back to the US, but how about I show them only my Bulgarian passport? It is critical for me to know what to do because I'm travelling with my children and any trouble I can avoid, I will.

Comment: US can't refuse US citizens to enter back the US, that is for sure, but ...how can I be sure that the other authorities will let me pass them without trouble?

Comment: @iva: If you enter Bulgaria with your Bulgarian passport (which you should), then you show the Bulgarian authorities your Bulgarian passport when you leave. It is important to always enter and leave using the same passport. However, the *airline* will also want to make sure you can enter the US when you arrive home in Chicago. For that, show the airline your US passport. Having dual passports is not unusual and there should be no problem. Note that the US government will *always* recommend that you travel using your US passport in all cases, even if you have another citizenship.